# Joint in curtain rods

Tags: joinery

How can I secure joint in wooden curtain rod to make sure it does not give way because of heavy curtains.  We already have a bracket in the middle and one at each end.

Many thanks

Comment: What is the diameter and length of the rod and what type of curtains (how heavy) will be used?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how this is done elsewhere in the world but where I am this is often (usually?) done using what's called a dowel screw:

[image: Dowel screw]

Dowel screws come in a few variants, try to buy the type exactly as in the picture with the unthreaded portion in the centre that you can grip with pliers or vice-grips.

**Note:** these must go into a pre-drilled holes in the wood or you'll almost certainly split the rod. Making the hole perfectly centred and square to the ends requires careful marking out and drilling.

I can say from personal experience that it's not easy to install these straight! But once installed they can work quite well to keep two halves of a curtain rail in line even with heavy velvet curtains and their lining.

Comment: Getting your holes centered can be made much easier with a [dowel center finder](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41FJJs-WZ5L._AC_UL115_.jpg) (borrowed from Amazon.com). A Google search on that link text will bring up a variety of ways of making your own, as well.

Answer (score 0):

A long scarf joint is the strongest solution I can think of. You would like a lot of length in the process, though.

Or laminating the piece before the rod is cut from it, or using a single contiguous piece in the first place.

Or consider replacing this with two rods each having its own bracket at which window center, avoiding the need to try to splice them at all. Which seems by far the simplest solution, and is probably what the folks over in the Home Improvement area of SE would tell you to do.

Mu?